# Updating child entities in One-To-Many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a parent entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="trm_agreements")
public class Agreement{


    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TRAGT_ID")
    private List<SubAgreement> subAgreements;

    // rest of the params
}
```

And a child entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="trm_sub_agreements")
public class SubAgreement{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    // rest of the params
}
```

Now, Lets say there are 3 sub-agreements associated with 1 agreement and I want to update that Agreement by adding 1 more sub-agreement and deleting 1 existing sub-agreement.

I'm not sure how to do this using springboot.

Comment: What you tried ?

Comment: This may help you https://gist.github.com/gtiwari333/8db9d5e4acf3dd17ea9bd65b22735eec

Comment: Currently, I'm asking fronted application to pass me the inserted, updated or deleted flags for each child entity and based upon that I'm modifying the sub-agreements. But, I don't think is a good idea.